# Laravel show error getimagesize on image update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am having a strange issue here on image update. After add a new product I need the option of update image and get this error while inserting it everything is ok.

```
getimagesize(2.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Here is my code

```
 $file = $request->image;

        if (isset($file))
        {
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $final_filename = $file->getFilename() . '.' . $extension;

            $new_height_75 = (75 * $height) / $width;
            $thumb_img_75 = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(75, $new_height_75);
            $thumb_img_75->save(public_path('attachments/product_images/thumbs_75').'/'.$final_filename,80);



            $new_height_250 = (250 * $height) / $width;
            $thumb_img_250 = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(250, $new_height_250);
            $thumb_img_250->save(public_path('attachments/product_images/thumbs_250').'/'.$final_filename,80);

            $new_height_150 = (150 * $height) / $width;
            $thumb_img_150 = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(150, $new_height_150);
            $thumb_img_150->save(public_path('attachments/product_images/thumbs_150').'/'.$final_filename,80);

            Storage::disk('product_images')->put($final_filename, File::get($file));



            $product->image = $final_filename;

        }
```

If i dd($file ); it gets the file I want to upload.
Thanks

Comment: In getimagesize() you need to specify path of the image. Probably it is not getting image path so it is giving you error.

Comment: @PankajMakwana i get the filename of the image '2.png', and while using the same method on store everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

why not you try laravel validator to validate image type as well as image file size https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-image